# Add a <br> every 5 item with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get an html `<br>` tag after a determined amount of elements with ng-repeat. As an example every 5th button gets a `<br>` appended to it. I tried multiple approaches but can't seem to get it right. I'd appreciate if anyone can give me some pointers on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small" ng-repeat="item in items"
     {{item}}
</button>
```

Comment: You just need to do nfIf or ngShow on the br when the index is divisible by 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for every fifth element using $index of ng-repeat, after that you can use ng-show directive to show `<br />` accordingly

```
<br ng-show="($index + 1) % 5 == 0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is supposed to be a row of buttons before each `<br>`? Easiest way to do this is to create a button container to repeat on, and making use of the [ngIf directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) alongside the [$index property of ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview) to determine if the `<br>` should exist:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small">{{ item }}</button>
  <br ng-if="$index && $index % 4 == 0">
</span>
```

The first `$index` inside the `ngIf` will evaluate to false on the first index (as it's the 0th index, so you don't get an early line break) and `$index % 4` will correspond to the 5th button overall accounting for the 0th index.